# Why defining private members below public members in C++?

Tags: c++, private

In C++ sometimes in class definition public members are declared at first and privates later. But the variables or data members are normally private and used by the public methods. So, in this case variables are used but not even declared yet. Thus the code become difficult to understand. But I found renowned programmers, sites or books to declare the private members later. Does anybody knows what is the reason?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308581/how-should-i-order-the-members-of-a-c-class

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778281/why-put-private-fields-and-methods-at-the-top-of-class

Answer (score 39):

I do things that way round since users of my class don't care about the private members, they're interested in the public API (i.e. how to use my class).

Also, in header files I'm generally just declaring member functions, rather than defining them, so I'm not accessing any private members anyway.

Comment: +1: The header file should act as a contract for the users of the class. No implementation belongs there.

Comment: Except for, of course, inline functions. However, in all but the most trivial cases, those should come after the class's definition.

Comment: Except for, templates too and stacks of libraries and so on.. Duplication is non-trivial if you fancy doing it all the time. Just because you can see accessibility does not mean you should tinker with it (there's analog in reflection for managed languages there if you read between the lines)... Good luck with 'contract' thinking in C++..

Comment: why not use the `struct` keyword in the first place?

Comment: @Florian somehow `struct` is associated strictly with dumb mixed-data type arrays, although in C++ its 100% the same as `class`, just public by default. I guess it comes down to C thinking in C++.

Answer (score 31):

We read text from top to bottom, so the most relevant information should be at the top. In a class definition, that's the public interface.

Answer (score 10):

Private members and implementation should be hidden from the header file. Putting the private member definitions at the bottom is a quick way to do so. Perhaps it is better to use the [Pimpl idiom](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/205918714;jsessionid=VITPS3S31ZIWDQE1GHRSKHWATMY32JVN) and hide the private part of your class in an internal struct.

Answer (score 2):

Normally private members don't matter. If I'm looking at a class to determine how to use it somewhere else in code I don't care about it's internals so put private members at the bottom since i don't need to know about them. If I"m modifying a class then I'll take the time to find the private members and know they'll be at the bottom instead of having to skim the entire class.

Answer (score 2):

We are like opposites: [My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778281/why-put-private-fields-and-methods-at-the-top-of-class)

My reasoning is that when you are becoming familiar with a class it is more beneficial to first get introduced to the public interface then go deeper into the private members when you need to. If you start by looking at the private members, you have no context how they are used.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed. Private members should be declared at bottom. The only good reason to declare private members first that i found, is when a function needs to get or return a custom data type, like: vector . The compiler will ask you about what kind of data is that.

But even, in that case i preffer to do:

```
{
private: /// advicing ofc theres more private below!
   earlier declare just of the type

public:


private:

};
```